# how to print the values of a nested dictionary in reverse order in python 3.6.3

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to print the values of a nested dictionary in reverse order as a string for example given the dictionary

```
M = {
  'data': 'k',
  'list': {
     'data': 'c',
     'list' : {
        'data': 'i',
        'list' : {
           'data': 's',
           'list':False
        }
     }
  }
}
```

should output

```
String = "sick"
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: From where do ppl get all these strange formatted data in the first place?

Comment: Although it is not explicitly stated in the name, *homework* is in fact *yourwork*.

Comment: Might make the most sense to build the string/list in forward order and then reverse it.

Comment: A dictionary in Python <3.6 is unordered.

Comment: @AntonvBR: that does not matter, every new characters is on a new level. So the last one is `M['data']`, the previous one `M['data']['list']`, the previous one `M['data']['list']['list']`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ohhh. it is even worse formatted than I thought.

Comment: @AntonvBR: Yes, my guess is that this is simply homework to practice recursion.

Comment: @AntonvBR and in python 3.6 it's just an implementation detail. If you want order, use `collections.OrderedDict`. But yes it doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 4):

Using a recursive approach,

```
def print_dict(d):
    if not d:
        return ''
    return print_dict(d['list']) + d['data']
```

Then you can call

```
M = {
    'data': 'k',
    'list': {
        'data': 'c',
        'list' : {
            'data': 'i',
            'list' : {
                'data': 's',
                'list': False
            }
        }
    }
}
print print_dict(M)
```

and it outputs

```
sick
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
M ={'data': 'k', 'list':{
'data': 'c', 'list' : {
'data': 'i', 'list' : {
'data': 's', 'list':False}}}}

from collections import abc
def nested_dict_iter(nested):
    for key, value in nested.items():
        if isinstance(value, abc.Mapping):
            yield from nested_dict_iter(value)
        else:
            yield value

print(''.join(reversed(list(nested_dict_iter(M))[:-1])))
```

Output:

```
sick
```

Some explanation:

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists/2158532#2158532) answer, a dict is iterable and therefore you can apply the nested container iterable formula to this problem.  This allows you to loop through the nested dictionary, while the `yield` returns a generator one item at a time.

Since the dictionary is nested, with one element at each depth, order is irrelevant.  Finally, I converted the generator to a list, removed the last element (which is `False`) and then joined a reversed version of the list, which outputs the correct string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-recursive approach:

```
def get_data(d):
    data = ''
    while d:
        data = d['data'] + data
        d = d['list']
    return data

print(get_data(M))
```

Output:

```
sick
```

The algorithm is simple: starts with `d` assigned to the nested dictionary. At each level, collect `d['data']`, then drill down to the next level util we hit `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
M ={'data': 'k', 'list':{
'data': 'c', 'list' : {
'data': 'i', 'list' : {
'data': 's', 'list':False}}}}    
def flatten(s):
  return [b if a == 'data' else (lambda x:None if not isinstance(x, dict) else flatten(x))(b) for a, b in s.items()]
def flatten_data(a):
   if not isinstance(a, list):
      yield a
   else:
      for i in a:
        for b in flatten_data(i):
          yield b

final_data = ''.join(filter(None, list(flatten_data(flatten(M)))))
```

Output:

```
sick
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```
 import json
M = {
  'data': 'k',
  'list': {
     'data': 'c',
     'list' : {
        'data': 'i',
        'list' : {
           'data': 's',
           'list':False
        }
     }
  }
}
data=[]
def recursive_a(kl_1):

    for i,j in kl_1.items():
        if isinstance(j,dict):
            recursive_a(j)
    data.append(kl_1.get('data'))
    return 0


print(recursive_a(json.loads(json.dumps(M))))

print("".join(data))
```

output:

```
sick
```